# Can unmanaged apps be updated with an InstallApplication command (or otherwise)?

Tags: swift, macos, mdm

On Apple's device management docs for the [InstallApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/install_an_app) command, it states:

> If the app is a managed app, this command updates it.

Presumably this means that if the app is not managed, then it will not be updated. Is that true? Not sure whether "if" means "if and only if" in this case.

If it indeed will not be updated, does this *also* mean that unmanaged apps can't be updated through MDM?

Comment: User will see popup that MDM server want install applications. If user agree then app will got installed and becomes managed. Then MDM server will be able to update it by itself.